# LLAMAINDEX - /pytorch/aten/src/ATen/native: indexSelectSmallIndex: block: [18,0,0], thread: [31,0,0] Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed

Tags: python, pytorch, llama, llama-index

I have problem with LLAMAINDEX

> /opt/pytorch/pytorch/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Indexing.cu:1237:
> indexSelectSmallIndex: block: [18,0,0], thread: [31,0,0] Assertion
> `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.

loading data

```
from llama_index import SimpleDirectoryReader
reader = SimpleDirectoryReader(
    input_files=["./data/paul_graham/paul_graham_essay1.txt"]
)
```

setup prompts - specific to StableLM

```
from llama_index.prompts import PromptTemplate

# This will wrap the default prompts that are internal to llama-index
# taken from https://huggingface.co/Writer/camel-5b-hf
query_wrapper_prompt = PromptTemplate(
    "Below is an instruction that describes a task. "
    "Write a response that appropriately completes the request.\n\n"
    "### Instruction:\n{query_str}\n\n### Response:"
)
```

load model

```
import torch

from llama_index import VectorStoreIndex, SimpleDirectoryReader, ServiceContext
from llama_index.llms import HuggingFaceLLM

llm = HuggingFaceLLM(
    context_window=2048,
    max_new_tokens=256,
    generate_kwargs={"temperature": 0.25, "do_sample": True},
    query_wrapper_prompt=query_wrapper_prompt,
    tokenizer_name="Writer/camel-5b-hf",
    model_name="Writer/camel-5b-hf",
    device_map="auto",
    tokenizer_kwargs={"max_length": 1024}, #2048

    # uncomment this if using CUDA to reduce memory usage
    model_kwargs={"torch_dtype": torch.float16}
)
service_context = ServiceContext.from_defaults(chunk_size=512, llm=llm, embed_model="local")
```

start indexing

```
from llama_index import (
    VectorStoreIndex,
    SimpleDirectoryReader,
    load_index_from_storage,
    StorageContext,
    ServiceContext
)

#service_context = ServiceContext.from_defaults(embed_model=embed_model, llm_predictor=llm_predictor)
service_context = ServiceContext.from_defaults(chunk_size=1024, llm=llm, embed_model="local")

index = VectorStoreIndex(documents,service_context=service_context)
```

get response from query where the error occurs

```
query_engine = index.as_query_engine()

response = query_engine.query(
    "What did the author do after his time at Y Combinator?"
)
print(response)
```

more stack trace of the error

> Token indices sequence length is longer than the specified maximum
> sequence length for this model (1815 > 512). Running this sequence
> through the model will result in indexing errors env:
> CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1 Setting `pad_token_id` to `eos_token_id`:50256
> for open-end generation. Setting `pad_token_id` to
> `eos_token_id`:50256 for open-end generation. Setting `pad_token_id`
> to `eos_token_id`:50256 for open-end generation. Setting
> `pad_token_id` to `eos_token_id`:50256 for open-end generation.
> Setting `pad_token_id` to `eos_token_id`:50256 for open-end
> generation. Setting `pad_token_id` to `eos_token_id`:50256 for
> open-end generation. Setting `pad_token_id` to `eos_token_id`:50256
> for open-end generation. Setting `pad_token_id` to
> `eos_token_id`:50256 for open-end generation. Setting `pad_token_id`
> to `eos_token_id`:50256 for open-end generation. Setting
> `pad_token_id` to `eos_token_id`:50256 for open-end generation.
> Setting `pad_token_id` to `eos_token_id`:50256 for open-end
> generation. Setting `pad_token_id` to `eos_token_id`:50256 for
> open-end generation. Setting `pad_token_id` to `eos_token_id`:50256
> for open-end generation. Setting `pad_token_id` to
> `eos_token_id`:50256 for open-end generation. This is a friendly
> reminder - the current text generation call will exceed the model's
> predefined maximum length (2048). Depending on the model, you may
> observe exceptions, performance degradation, or nothing at all.
> /opt/pytorch/pytorch/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Indexing.cu:1237:
> indexSelectSmallIndex: block: [22,0,0], thread: [0,0,0] Assertion
> `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.
> /opt/pytorch/pytorch/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Indexing.cu:1237:
> indexSelectSmallIndex: block: [22,0,0], thread: [1,0,0] Assertion
> `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.
> /opt/pytorch/pytorch/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Indexing.cu:1237:
> indexSelectSmallIndex: block: [22,0,0], thread: [2,0,0] Assertion
> `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.
> /opt/pytorch/pytorch/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Indexing.cu:1237:
> indexSelectSmallIndex: block: [22,0,0], thread: [3,0,0] Assertion
> `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.
> /opt/pytorch/pytorch/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Indexing.cu:1237:
> indexSelectSmallIndex: block: [22,0,0], thread: [4,0,0] Assertion
> `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.
> /opt/pytorch/pytorch/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Indexing.cu:1237:
> indexSelectSmallIndex: block: [22,0,0], thread: [5,0,0] Assertion
> `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.
> /opt/pytorch/pytorch/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Indexing.cu:1237:
> indexSelectSmallIndex: block: [22,0,0], thread: [6,0,0] Assertion
> `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue reducing max_new_tokens

```
llm = HuggingFaceLLM(
    context_window=2048,
    max_new_tokens=128, #256
    generate_kwargs={"do_sample": True},
```